# Django admin, is there any option like "copy to new"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have made some fields of my model uneditable after creation by below:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        return self.readonly_fields + ('field1',)
    else:
        return self.readonly_fields
```

I want to find an option like "copy to new" to help me to copy every field of the old record to new one and works just like "add" option in which every field is editable. Then I will edit some fields and save it.

I can only find some options like "save as new" or "add another". In "save as new" option, errors were reported because the uneditable field can't be saved but turn out to be empty. In "add another" option, it is simply an add action with empty fields.

Can someone guide me how can i achieve this and where to look for it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you intend to edit the fields, why do you make them uneditable at first?

Comment: Yes, it seems a little strange. We want to let users create records and then limit them to edit some key fields after creation. However, we want to provide an easy way for them to create the new records with existing records.